# XML connectivity for booking website

Tags: xml, connectivity

I am new to XML and need headstart for a car hire website which requires XML connectivity with its partners. So please help understand what do I need to know to start it?
Thanks for help!

Comment: XML is just a data format. The phrase "XML connectivity" doesn't make sense. Besides, chances are you should be asking the partners.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the XML definitions from the partners which are either in XSD (XML Schema) or DTD format. And then look into the XML tools for your language to emit that XML. There are plenty of online resources which will help you understand XML.